# Azure Bot App Registration requiring multi-tenancy when single-tenant is prefered

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

I have an application I need to deploy that is requiring the App Registration to be "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)". What would the implication of setting this be? The application does not work if I set it to just "Accounts in this organizational directory only ( only - Single tenant)". The application using this App Registration is a Bot Framework application.

Where in the Bot framework code would there be some dependency on multi-tenancy? I would prefer to keep it as single tenant.

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multi-tenant organization is what enables the Azure Bot Service servers (in the botframework.com tenant) to authenticate requests coming from the bot (registered in the customer's tenant) through our servers. It's part of our service to service authentication protocol. it is not used for other purposes, and not to have any claims added to it for other access.

So don't worry about that your tenant's data will be leaked to other tenants.

See a similar post [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/308518/bot-framework-app-registration-single-tenant-vs-mu.html).

Comment: Thanks Allen! That helped.

Comment: hey Allen, you mean if we are implementing an authentication/sso in our bot, we need to make sure that the azure bot created will be `MultiTenant` Bot Type and the app registration should also `MultiTenant` under `Supported account types`? Thanks!

Comment: @Allen, presumably that means there's no way out of box to lock a bot to being available just in a single tenant? Someone with the Azure App Id could connect to the bot directly in Teams. It would require the developer to implement something like the middleware sample that blocks calls from non-white-listed tenants, correct?