# Can Azure Bot App Reg for Microsoft Teams use Single Tenant?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

Right now, I have MS Teams Bot running under App Registration configured to use "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)".

To begin with, I did a research on that topic and I am writing this question having in mind following resources:

- [Comment on issue #9498 @ azure-sdk-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9498#issuecomment-575332273)
- [Azure Bot App Registration requiring multi-tenancy when single-tenant is prefered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811870/azure-bot-app-registration-requiring-multi-tenancy-when-single-tenant-is-prefere)
- [Bot Framework - App registration - Single tenant vs Multi tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/308518/bot-framework-app-registration-single-tenant-vs-mu.html)

All these answers, from my understanding, comes to this:

- prior to late 2021 only Multi-tenant apps as bot identity were supported
- now I should be able to use the Single-tenat for app registration, but that requires additional configuration
- moment when mentioned changes are in effect is a moment when Bot is trying to authenticate

As other bots imperatively (explicitly) authorize using ex. `MicrosoftAppCredentials` - MS Teams Bots have their authorization details configured declaratively in XML files like `appsettings.json` in bot service.

**How can I use Single tenant App Registration with Azure Bot used in MS Teams?** Or is it not possible currently?

**EDIT**:
For future reader: using the answer, I prepared two places where you can access TenantId of incoming activity to perform whitelisting validation (in Multi-tenant setup, because Single-tenant is still not working on Teams):

1. In `BotController`:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            // Here using 
            //this.Request.Headers["X-Ms-Tenant-Id"].ToString()
        }
```

2. In `TeamsActivityHandler` instance method override:

```cs
    internal class /***/ : TeamsActivityHandler
    {
        //any method that have access to TurnContext or Activity
        public override Task /***/(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, ...)
        {
            // Here using
            //turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId
        }
    }
```

Having the TenantId you can compare it to the allowed tenant and reject or allow accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this with another user on this site recently, where Proactive Messaging would not work because they had selected Single Tenant. It's a recent option, and it seems broken from my research - I would go with the MultiTenant option. If you really need to block the bot from being accessible from other tenants (which could well be recommended as it's possible for a bot to be access by any user in any Teams tenant, it might be best to white-list your Tenant Id(s). There's an old sample on how to do this here - haven't tested if it's still working: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/master/template-bot-master-csharp/middleware/Middleware.cs

Comment: @Kamil - Could you please confirm if the above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still looking for any help?

Comment: Actually, this is a constructive advice - that Single Tenancy is not supported in Teams as it is right now - and I can instead whitelist tenant!
@Nivedipa-MSFT yeah, I think it is enough, :) I will mark it as an answer and update my question accordingly.

Comment: Single Tenant won't block access by users who install your bot in their tenant. As currently implemented, it's not designed to control user access at all. It only blocks Azure resources from outside tenants. Blocking users would be done by denying apps (as mentioned) or by user auth.

Teams *has* implemented Single Tenancy support, incidentally, for the above definition.

Comment: @AP01, thanks for jumping in here. Can you please explain more: 1. "It only blocks Azure resources from outside tenants" - what does this mean exactly, and 2. "Teams has implemented Single Tenancy support, incidentally, for the above definition" - what does this mean also, and how does it manifest?

Comment: It means, essentially, that a single tenant bot will not be able to connect to Azure resources (such as Cosmos) that are part of another tenant. So if you have a bot in tenant 1 and you try to persist data to a Cosmos DB instance in tenant 2, it will fail. The auth will fail because Azure will prevent these resources from obtaining cross-tenant tokens. In terms of Teams, a single tenant bot should work when you install a manifest the same way a multi tenant bot would. The user will be able to interact with the bot regardless of which tenant the user is in.

Comment: thanks, that definitely helps to clarify.

Comment: @AP01 from your comment, I'm getting the impression that when I choose Single-tenant for App Registration, bot should work fine. But when I do so, when I post an action on the Teams App, on the App Service (.NET Bot Service deployed on Azure) I'm getting the 
`AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'XXXXXX-ee21-40ad-YYYY-76b5316d7d9a' was not found in the directory 'd6d49420-f39b-4df7-a1dc-d59a935871db'` when I execute `await TeamsInfo.GetTeamDetailsAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id, cancellationToken)`? And yes, I did respond with the justInTimeInstall before.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your manifest, or perhaps the application in question is not the bot, but rather some other service the bot connects to? Verify what resource that AppId corresponds to and ensure that it's supposed to be reachable.

Comment: @AP01 I'm using the Bot Framework 4.15.2 on .NET application that is deployed as Azure App Service. In `appsettings.json` I am having the Client ID, Secret and Tenant ID of App Registration XYZ. XYZ's Supported account types are "My organization only" (Single-tenant). I have Azure Bot ABC configured with Single-tenancy and identifying itself using App Registration XYZ. I have MS Teams App that have messaging extension capability and in its `manifest.xml` have XYZ Client ID set as `botID` in `bots` and `composeExtensions` sections.
All are created in the same Resource Group, same Tenant.

Comment: Can you suggest what could be wrong in this setup @AP01? The only thing that comes to my mind is, that in `manifest.xml` I should place a Azure Bot ID - but I can't find one on the Azure Portal.

Comment: Your `Azure Bot` resource in Azure has an ID. This is the AppId which you need in the Teams manifest.

Comment: @AP01 is this Resource ID? Something like `/subscriptions/{GUID}/resourceGroups/{Resource_Group}/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/{Name_Of_Bot}`? If not, where I can find it?

Comment: Click on the bot, go the left-side menu, find the blade marked `Configuration` and click on it. On that page will be a field marked `Microsoft App ID`

Comment: Well @AP01 this is exactly the Id of the App Registration. So, my configuration so far is correct.